# Minimal generators of an ideal

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

Take $S$ and $T$ two subsets of homogeneous elements of the associative noncommutative free algebra $F$ over a field $k$ generated by a set $X$, provided with a positive grading. 
To exclude pathologies $S$ and $T$ are contained in $\bar{F}.\bar{F}$, $\bar{F}$ denoting the augmentation ideal of $F$. 
If $S$ and $T$ are minimal generator sets for their respective generated ideals, is it the same true for the set $S.T$ of products of elements of $S$ and $T$?

Comment: What do you mean by «to exclude pathologies»? The set $F\cdot F$ is just $F$.

Comment: I meant $\bar{F}.\bar{F}$, $\bar{F}$ denoting the augmentation ideal. I've already edited it. Thanks for pointing it out. 

Comment: Left ideals? Right ideals? Two-sided ideals?

Comment: I was just using (what I suppose is) the standard convention (e.g. in the book of J. McConnell and J. Robson, or in the one of F. Anderson and K. Fuller): ideal = two-sided ideal. Thanks for the comment. 

Comment: In my opinion one should specify when ideals are two-sided.

Comment: By the references I gave before it would be my opinion that (at least) several (of the main) experts on the area believe the opposite to what you have stated. In any case, the statement (now) seems to be clear. Thanks for your opinion. 